# Block RSS feed of your answers/comments on target website

Tags: support, feed

Is it possible to block RSS feeds from my answers/comments that display on a website outside of SO?

A website of a company I used to work for has SO rss feeds implemented on their blog - my account is also part of those feeds, but they never removed my account once I left their company. Is there any way to block those feeds from my SO account, since they take credit of my answers and the way it is implemented it looks like if I still work for them.

Comment: You can email 'team@stackexchange.com' to request that the content be disassociated from your account, but it sounds to me like you have a legal issue with your former employer that extends beyond the scope of this technical detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Do note that when you post to Stack Overflow, you license your contributions under the [CC Wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). As long as your former employer links back to the content, they are within their rights to republish any of your contributions.

You'll have to take this up with that company and and ask them to desist from publishing your answers, if that is what you have a problem with. Stack Overflow cannot help you there.

Comment: That's what I suspected- thanks for clarification. I'm fine with all CC - just don't want my name to show up under "our employers SO activity" section - which is kinda annoying.